# Undetected_Chromedriver is not using the user-data folder that I specified

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

I'm trying to make undetected_chromedriver use specific user-data of chrome that I put in a folder on my desktop, but it's not using that folder, it's rather using the default folder of chrome, while normal selenium webdriver seems to work. The folder on my desktop is called 'data' and inside there, there's 10's of 'data(number)' folders, and to make it run simultaneously I had to have multiple user-data folders. My code:

```
from undetected_chromedriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions

data = "0"
options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\pvand\\Desktop\\data\\data{data}\\profile {data}")

with Chrome(options=options) as driver:
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

I expected to use the user-data folders that are specified in the code, but it's not doing that, it's using the user-data of the default AppData\Local\Google\Chrome folder instead